# C# - Se detectó una referencia circular al serializar un objeto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación aspnet mvc5 y EF , tengo los modelos a partir de la BD en concreto tengo esto que es para los tipos de productos que tienen más articulos

```
namespace testweb.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class TipoProductos
    {
        public TipoProductos()
        {
            this.Articulos = new HashSet<Articulos>();
        }

        public short tipoProducto { get; set; }
        public string Familia { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public string activo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> iva { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Articulos> Articulos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Luego tengo en el controlador para devolver un JSON con los distintos registros de este modelo

```
public JsonResult getProductCategories()
{
    List<TipoProductos> categorias = new List<TipoProductos>();
    categorias = db.TipoProductos.OrderBy(a => a.Descripcion).ToList();
    return new JsonResult { Data = categorias, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Y el archivo JS desde donde hago la petición

```
var CategoriasProductos = []

//obtener categorias desde la BD
function LoadCategory(element) {
    if (CategoriasProductos.length == 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Ventas/getProductCategories',
            success: function (data) {
                CategoriasProductos = data;
                renderCategory(element);
            },

            error: function (error) {
                console.log('*** error   --> ' + error.responseText);
            },

        })
    }
    else {
        renderCategory(element);
    }
}
```

El error que recibo al hacer la petición al controlador es este

> Se detectó una referencia circular al serializar un objeto de tipo 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Articulos

¿Cuál es la mejor forma para solucionar esto? Leyendo he visto que se puede hacer poniendo el atributo ScriptIgnore en el modelo. ¿Qué me recomendáis?

---

Modelo *Articulos*:

```
namespace testweb.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public partial class Articulos
    {
        public Articulos()
        {
            this.AlbaranesLinias = new HashSet<AlbaranesLinias>();
            this.ArticulosHistoricoPrecios = new HashSet<ArticulosHistoricoPrecios>();
            this.Stock = new HashSet<Stock>();
            this.VentasLinias = new HashSet<VentasLinias>();
        }


        public string weblogin { get; set; }
        public byte tienda { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public short proveedor { get; set; }


        [ScriptIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<AlbaranesLinias> AlbaranesLinias { get; set; }
        [ScriptIgnore]
        public virtual Proveedores Proveedores { get; set; }
        [ScriptIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<ArticulosHistoricoPrecios> ArticulosHistoricoPrecios { get; set; }
        [ScriptIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<Stock> Stock { get; set; }
        [ScriptIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<VentasLinias> VentasLinias { get; set; }
        [ScriptIgnore]
        public virtual TipoProductos TipoProductos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Modelo *tipoProductos*:

```
namespace testweb.Models
{
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public partial class TipoProductos
    {
        public TipoProductos()
        {
           this.Articulos = new HashSet<Articulos>();
        }

        public short tipoProducto { get; set; }
        public string Familia { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public string tipo1 { get; set; }
        public string tipo2 { get; set; }
        public string tipo3 { get; set; }
        public string activo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> iva { get; set; }

        //[ScriptIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<Articulos> Articulos { get; set; }

    }
}
```

He puesto el código que me has puesto del JsonResult de getProductCategories y me devuelve este error:

> Error 1   No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' en
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

---

Me faltaría hacer que el resultado esté agrupado por los campos *Familia* para ello pongo este código:

```
public JsonResult getProductCategories()
    {
        var categorias = db.TipoProductos.OrderBy(a => a.Descripcion)
                            .GroupBy(p => p.Familia)
                            .Select(c => new { Descripcion = c.Descripcion, Familia = c.Familia, TipoProducto = c.tipoProducto, Activo = c.activo })
                            .ToList();
        return new JsonResult { Data = categorias, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

Pero si intento agrupar por el campo Familia me da este error

> `Error    4   'System.Linq.IGrouping'
>   no contiene una definición de 'activo'  ni se encontró ningún método
>   de extensión 'activo'   que acepte un primer argumento de tipo
>   'System.Linq.IGrouping'  (¿falta
>   una directiva de uso o una referencia de ensamblado?).

Comment: Podrías postear el código de `Articulos`, creo que si tienes una variable que haga referencia a `TipoProductos` el problema estará ahí y si es eso hay varias formas de solucionarlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si añades `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]` al principio de tus clases de datos `TiposProducts` y `Articulos` evitarás ese fallo al serializar por referencia cíclica.

Comment: gracias lo he probado y funciona

Comment: @ilernet, si esta respuesta te ha solucionado tu problema, recuerda que puedes [aceptar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Gracias @MauricioAriasOlave

Answer (score 1):

La verdad es que es complicado este tema ya que el problema se encuentra en la deserialización de la respuesta de tu controller a la view. Yo te recomiendo realices una proyección, esto es, devolver un tipo anónimo con las propiedades que realmente a la vista y que esta se encargue de renderizar. (fijate en el `Select` de la consulta)

```
public JsonResult getProductCategories()
{
    var categorias = db.TipoProductos.OrderBy(a => a.Descripcion)
                        .Select(c => new{ Descripcion = c.Descripcion, Familia = c.Familia, TipoProducto = c.tipoProducto, Activo = c.activo}) 
                        .ToList();
    return new JsonResult { Data = categorias, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Comment: He probado este JsonResult y el error que me da es este                                               Error 1 No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List' en 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Comment: Edito mi codigo

Comment: muchas gracias , ahora tengo problemas para hacer la agrupación he respondido más abajo con mi código propuesto. gracias