# Se detectó una referencia circular al serializar un objeto de tipo 'HighSchool.Common.Models.Enroll_Student'

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net

Buen dia
tengo el siguiente problema, estoy tratando de enviado un metodo post desde un formulario por medio de ajax a un metodo web. al realizar la consulta en la base de datos trae como resultado un objeto sin ningun problema pero al realizar la seralizacion con json me arroja el siguiente error:

> Se detectó una referencia circular al serializar un objeto de tipo 'HighSchool.Common.Models.Enroll_Student'.

He intentado colocar 
`[JsonIgnore]` tambien `[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute]`en la clase pero sigue dando este error, 
Tambien intente `db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` pero no funciono.
Mis clases son las siguientes:

```
 public class UserSchool
{

    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "E-Mail")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is required")]
    [StringLength(50)]//only you can to write 50 characters
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    // [Index("UserNameIndex", Isnique = true)]
    public string EmailUser { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nombres")]
    [Required]
    public string FirstNameUser { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Apellidos")]
    [Required]
    public string LastNameUser { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.FirstNameUser, this.LastNameUser); }
    }
    [Display(Name = "Telefono")]
    public string PhoneUser { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Direccion de residencia")]
    [Required]
    public string AddressUser { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fecha de nacimiento")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]// para que nos muestre el calendario
    public DateTime DateBirthdayUser{ get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Imagen")]
    public string PhotoUser { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Estudiante")]
    public bool IsStudentUser { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Profesor")]
    public bool IsTeacherUser { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sistemas")]
    public bool IsSystemUser { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Numero de documento")]
    public string NumberDocumentUsers { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo de documento")]
    public int TypeDocumentId { get; set; }
    public virtual TypeDocument TypeDocument { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Pais de nacimiento")]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Departamento de nacimiento")]
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public virtual State State { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Ciudad de nacimento")]
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public virtual City City { get; set; }



    public virtual ICollection<ContactEmergency> ContactEmergencies { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Enroll_Student> Enroll_Students { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Enroll_Teacher_Subject> Enroll_Teacher_Subjects { get; set; }


}
```

esta es la clase que relaciona con UserSchool

```
public class Enroll_Student
{
    [Key]
    public int Enroll_StudentId { get; set; }

    [Required]   
    [Display(Name = "Fecha de Matricula")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DateEnroll_Student { get; set; }     


    [Display(Name = "Estudiante")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserSchool UserSchool { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Grado")]
    public int LevelId { get; set; }
    public virtual Level Level { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Anno lectivo")]
    public int AnnoLectivoId { get; set; }
    public virtual AnnoLectivo AnnoLectivo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Enroll_Student_Subject_Teacher> Enroll_Student_Subject_Teachers { get; set; }


}
```

El metodo

```
public JsonResult GetEnroll_student1(string SearchValue)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var listEstudianteEnroll = db.Enroll_Student.Join(db.UserSchools,
                                                           es => es.UserId,
                                                           u => u.UserId,
                                                           (es, u) =>
                                                           new { es, u })
                                                           .FirstOrDefault(x => x.u.NumberDocumentUsers == SearchValue);


        return Json(listEstudianteEnroll, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: No sé si votar como duplicada, pero desde luego el problema es el mismo que se presenta en [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/203073/chrome-me-env%C3%ADa-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)

Comment: Y aquí otra [pregunta similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/70305/c-se-detect%C3%B3-una-referencia-circular-al-serializar-un-objeto), también con [tag:c#].

Comment: Sip.. hay una relacion circular entre user_school y Enroll_Student. no entiendo el sentido de eso.

Comment: Existen varios post con el mismo titulo pero las respuestas que dan hasta ahora no me han servido. Por ese motivo hice una nueva pregunta

Comment: Ok. Porfa mira [ask] y tambien hace el [tour]. Cuanda pasan esas cosas, tenes que explicar porque no te sirvieron esas respuestas. No entiendo porque tenes esa relacion circular asi.

Comment: Enroll_Student agrega a un usuario es por eso que tiene un UserId  y en user_school  hice una relacion virtual Enroll_Students,

Comment: Y como querrias que quede tu Json? eso es importante, para saber que propiedad ignorar.

Comment: Necesito que del class UserSchool me arroje las propiedades: 
 NumberDocumentUsers, AddressUser, PhoneUser  y de la class Enroll_Student solo la propiedad: DateEnroll_Student

Comment: Aclara tambien a que paquete pertenece ese Json que estas usando para serializar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tienes que devolver como respuesta de un action que serializa a json las entidades persistentes que mapeas con entity framework ya que lazy load genera ste problema

```
 public JsonResult GetEnroll_student1(string SearchValue)
{

    var listEstudianteEnroll = (from es in db.Enroll_Student
                                join u from db.UserSchools on es.UserId equals u.UserId 
                                where u.NumberDocumentUsers == SearchValue
                                select EstudentDto()
                                {
                                    prop1 = es.prop1,
                                    prop2 = es.prop2,
                                    prop3 = u.prop1
                                }).ToList();


    return Json(listEstudianteEnroll, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

esto es a modo de ejemplo, pero tienes que crear la clase `EstudentDto` que sera la que se serialice con las propiedades que quieres enviar, en este punto si quieres te puees ayudar con [automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started)

Pero remarco que `NUNCA` se devuelve las entidades que usas en al persistencia como repsuesta de un json

Nota: me gusta mas a notacion linq para unir entidades

Comment: Gracias voy intentar hacerlo como me dices...

Comment: Gracias Leandro, me funciono...